# Novel: Wizard's memoirs, servant to a god, long timespan

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find a fantasy novel I read about the life of a wizard. He started out as a normal person, but became a servant of a god (I think the god treated him as a friend and student). He played a kind of puppet master role in the history of the world he lived in, which he affected over a long timespan (thousands of years?). There were other wizards who were also servants of this god, and I seem to remember that one of them was or became a rival or the bad guy, potentially serving another god in the process.

I think the book was published in the 90's, but I'm not certain of it. I also think there were other books in the series after it, or that this book was a prequel of some kind.

Comment: Does this count as a duplicate? It's from the same series but this is about the prequel and not the main series, it seems like they're fairly different and could be considered separate series

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like it could be *[Belgarath the Sorcerer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/189802.Belgarath_the_Sorcerer)* by David and Leigh Eddings, prequel book to the *Belgariad* and *Mallorean* series.

> When the world was young and Gods still walked among their mortal children, a headstrong orphan boy set out to explore the world. Thus began the extraordinary adventures that would mold that youthful vagabond into a man, and the man into the finely honed instrument of Prophecy known to all the world as Belgarath the Sorcerer.
>
> Then came the dark day when the Dark God Torak split the world asunder, and the God Aldur and his disciples began their monumental labor to set Destiny aright. Foremost among their number was Belgarath. His ceaseless devotion was foredoomed to cost him that which he held most dear--even as his loyal service would extend through echoing centuries of loss, of struggle, and of ultimate triumph.

All of the facts fit from Belgarath's lifetime of several thousand years to him and others being servants of the god Aldur, to his brother Zedar betraying Aldur and stealing the orb for Torak.

[The Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgarath_the_Sorcerer) notes that it is indeed written as an autobiography:

> The book opens shortly after the end of The Malloreon with Belgarion, with help from Durnik, pestering Belgarath to write an autobiographical account of the events prior to The Belgariad. The core of the book is in the form of Belgarath's memoirs starting with his becoming an outcast from his village and becoming first disciple of the god Aldur and ending with the birth of Belgarion—a span of about seven thousand years.

Comment: Belgarath was my initial thought too

Comment: Will do, although it's got to wait a few minutes before I can. Was this something you already knew? I didn't have any luck searching for it

Comment: I just recently grabbed the *Pawn of Prophecy* audiobook, first book of the *Belgariad*. As one critic put it, Eddings basically write one great story in his career, but he's made a living of continuing and rewriting it since, and he's good at it.

Comment: The books were childhood favorites of mine.

Comment: I remember really liking his characters, guess I'll check out the rest of the series :)

Comment: I thought of this as soon as I saw the title :-)

Comment: I've thought about getting into the Belgariad a number of times. Do Edding's novels still read well to this day? A lot of late 20th century fantasy fiction was derivative of Tolkien - there's a young, naive protagonist, a quest, a Dark Lord, etc.

Comment: @RobertF: It's all pretty strictly formula, but it's very well-executed formula (which was the point of it, as I recall, Eddings leaving a writing seminar about cliches and deciding he was going to write a walking cliche and make it good), and I think it does hold up. I have mixed opinions, incidentally, on the audiobook I got of it. The somewhat caricaturish accents on the various nationalities make the parallels to our own culture more stark, and Belgarath is basically Sean Connery.

Comment: @RobertF I think so. Some of it *is* a bit samey, but as FuzzyBoots said, that's kind of by design and the author has a good in-universe excuse for it. It has a lot of clear-cut and well-imagined, if somewhat caricatured, characters, and some of the dialogue is really gold.